# Oracle SQL to add exception to join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query:

```
select emp_id,emp_name,emp_org from employees a, emp_data b, emp_address c 
where a.emp_id(+) = b.emp_data and b.emp_data_id(+) = c.emp_id 
and c.emp_id (+) = a.emp_id
```

The problem is one of the employees doesn't have entry in emp_address table. But we still want that employees records to also populate despite not having entry in emp_address table.

Full outer join doesnt seem applicable.

Please help?

Comment: Please use the explizit (left) join syntax instead of the implizit style using where statement

Comment: explicit join can alter data?

Comment: also can i use both implicit and explicit join in a table?

Comment: No joins doesn't alter data, and no you can't/shouldn't

Comment: `a`, `b` and `c` are poor table aliases. Choose aliases that make sense, e.g. `e` for employees, `a` for address etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using `left join` should give you the correct result:

```
select emp_id,emp_name,emp_org 
from employees a left join emp_data b on a.emp_id = b.emp_data 
left join emp_address c on b.emp_data_id = c.emp_id
```

Comment: can i use both implicit and explicit join on same table?

Comment: On the same table yes, in the same statement you shouldn't do it

Comment: @Velocity Yes, you can mix join types the ANSI joins need to be first and the legacy comma joins last - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75768004/1509264

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not work, you get the error:

> ```
> ORA-01416: two tables cannot be outer-joined to each other
> ```

This is because you join `b` to `a` and `a` to `c` and `c` to `b` and you have created a ring of outer joins.

Your problem is:

> one of the employees doesn't have entry in `emp_address` table. But we still want that employees records to also populate despite not having entry in emp_address table.

So if we have some sample data that mocks that condition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (emp_id PRIMARY KEY, emp_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beryl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE emp_data (emp_data PRIMARY KEY, emp_data_id) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE emp_address (emp_id PRIMARY KEY, emp_org) AS
SELECT 1, 'Street A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Road B'   FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE emp_address ADD CONSTRAINT emp_address__emp_id__fk
  FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES employees (emp_id);

ALTER TABLE emp_data ADD CONSTRAINT emp_data__emp_data__fk
  FOREIGN KEY (emp_data) REFERENCES employees (emp_id);
```

---

As an aside, we could also try to add the constraint similar to your third join condition (but in the reverse direction so there is not the ring of referential constraints):

```
ALTER TABLE emp_data ADD CONSTRAINT emp_data__emp_data_id__fk
  FOREIGN KEY (emp_data_id) REFERENCES emp_address (emp_id);
```

But that would raise the exception:

```
ORA-02298: cannot validate (FIDDLE_AGHHWSEJWWMNIOLVLAIX.EMP_DATA__EMP_DATA_ID__FK) - parent keys not found
```

As there is no address data for `Carol`.

I'm not sure, logically why you would want a relationship there unless there is a one-to-one relationship (rather than a one-to-zero-or-one relationship) between `employees` and `emp_address` and then you need to ask why there would be a separate table.

---

Then if you query and join in the direction of the referential constraints:

```sql
select a.emp_id,
       a.emp_name,
       c.emp_org
from   employees a,
       emp_data b,
       emp_address c 
where  a.emp_id = c.emp_id(+)
and    a.emp_id = b.emp_data(+)
and    c.emp_id = b.emp_data_id(+)
```

The output is:

| EMP_ID | EMP_NAME | EMP_ORG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | Street A |
| 2 | Beryl | Road B |
| 3 | Carol | *null* |

Which can be written equivalently using modern ANSI joins:

```sql
select e.emp_id,
       e.emp_name,
       a.emp_org
from   employees e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_address a
       ON (e.emp_id = a.emp_id)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_data d
       ON (e.emp_id = d.emp_data AND a.emp_id = d.emp_data_id);
```

and outputs the same.

*Note: You should check whether you need the filter `emp_address.emp_id = emp_data.emp_data_id` - I do not think it, logically, makes sense and the output is identical without it for this sample data but since you haven't described your tables or the logic then you may have different business logic where it does make sense to include that join.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gz9AiIUL)